# Merge sort using vectors C++ (I have no idea what I'm missing in my implementation)

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am very confused. I have been given a merge method that I know works

```
template<typename T, typename X>
void merge(std::vector<T>& vec, X start, X mid, X end) { ... }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the merge sort method.

This is what I have so far:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
void merge_sort(std::vector<T>& vec, X begin, X end) {
    if (start >= end) return;
        X midpoint = ( start + end ) / 2;
        merge_sort(vec, begin, midpoint);
        merge_sort(vec, midpoint + 1, end);
        merge(vec, begin, midpoint, end);

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need help figuring this out and also the reasons why what I did was wrong. I can't offer the merge method code, but I know for a fact it works.

If this is somehow correct, what should I put in main to make sure I am testing it properly.

Comment: you seem to be merging `std::vectors` in-place, which is not a very good idea. Also what exaclty is not working? I don't see how it can even compile with no `start` definition in your function template

Comment: can you elaborate? I am new to this so in-place seems foreign to me.

Comment: If the code is going to use ending iterators, it would be better to make the two merge_sort calls `merge_sort(vec, begin, midpoint);` and `merge_sort(vec, midpoint, end);`  (not midpoint+1).

Comment: well, by in-place I mean you're merging 2 parts of a vector into that same vector, this (depending on `merge` implementation) could result either in some overwritings and data loss, or in extremely bad performance

Comment: The `in place` won't be an issue if merge() creates a temporary vector to use for the merge process, doing a copy before or after so that the sorted data ends up back in vec.

Comment: @rcgldr good point, but allocations though...

Comment: the end, midpoint and begin should be indices of the vector. @Ap31 I think I get what your saying. The merge method should be creating a temp vector that is the sorted data, then inputting that sorted data into the original vector (overwriting the data in the original vector) -- that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @120394999 OK, let's say `merge` just works, can you say what is the problem/error? Did you try to compile the code?

Comment: @Ap31 I compiled the code and it just doesn't sort properly. The numbers are all out of order. merge_sort(input,0,10); Input is a vector of ints

Comment: how can it possibly compile with no `start` definition? are you sure you're instantiating the template?

Comment: @Ap31 the start should say begin. I have it as begin in my code.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code (for example why do you need the `S` template parameter if you don't use it anywhere?). I also have a couple of questions: 1) Why are you sure that `merge` works correctly? 2) Why can't you post it's code (perhaps you don't have it?)

Comment: In the template for merge_sort, you have typename S, but the parameters are using type X. As I commented before, the "end" index should be 1 past the "last" index of the vector. This way, "begin" corresponds to vec.begin(), and "end" corresponds to vec.end().